# wordpress template is different on explorer and in chrome and firefox

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have made a website with wordpress. I had to change few things from the css to make the design to be what I want exactly.

I do get the full design that I want from chrome and firefox but the results are different in internet explorer.

chrome:
[image]

firefox:
[image]

explorer:
[image]

I dont understand what goes wrong to honest, and why this happens.
why the css doesnt stay the same for every broweser. Am I doing something to cause this?

Comment: This is quite a broad question but not all browsers are the same. Internet Explorer is known to not support all CSS3 features and there are also specific workarounds for some. You can this website to see which browser support what: https://caniuse.com/

Comment: @Kyon147 can u explain this me, how this works? there is  no way to make sure all the browser use the same css??

Comment: The browser decides what to do with CSS, which means that also decides what is supported. When browsers are updated they include additional support for newer CSS rules but IE does not support everything the other browser do and probably never will. You'll need to tweak the CSS to make it work how you want for IE if you want to support it.

Comment: @Kyon147 THANK YOU I get it now, do u have any idea how to tweak the css to make it work?

Comment: You'll need to learn basic html and css. This should get you started here: https://www.w3schools.com/css/